# How do I take a php variable that has an sql query inside it and add it to an existing sql query using $db->updatePhoneNumbers()?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays

I am trying to make a database of Users. One user can have an indefinite number of phone numbers. So in the form I’ve created a js function that will give me new input fields and they put the information into a nestled array.

I am doing a double foreach loop to go through my array, and add SQL queries to it based on if the id already exists and just needs to be updated or if it's entirely new and needs to be inserted. I add these SQL queries to a variable $phoneSql . When I echo that variable, it does contain a valid SQL query which works if I try it directly in phpMyAdmin.

This is the foreach loop code:

```
 $phoneSql = 'SELECT id FROM user WHERE id = '.$id.' INTO @id;';
 foreach($_POST['phone'] as $key => $value) {
    foreach($_POST['user'][$key] as $id => $number) {
        if($id == 0 && !$number == ''){
            $phoneSql .= 'INSERT INTO phone_number (id, user_id, number) VALUES (NULL, @id, "'.$number.'");';
            } else if (!$number == '') {
                $phoneSql .= 'UPDATE phone_numbers SET user_id = @id,  number = "'.$number.'" WHERE id = '.$id.';';
            } 
        }
    }
```

I have one edit.php page with the form, which posts to update.php where I have the foreach loop from above and following code:

```
$db->updatePhoneNumber($phoneSql);
```

It also gets the $id from the user I’m editing at the moment. Then it gets sent to db.php and into this function:

```
public function updatePhoneNumbers($phoneSql) {
    $ phoneSql = $ phoneSql;

    $sth = $this->dbh->prepare($phoneSql);
    $sth->execute();
    if ($sth->execute()) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

But this is not working. Can I add a variable with sql queries into a function like that or do I have to do it some other way? I’m quite new to this so I’m not sure how to proceed. I’ve tried searching for a solution but haven’t found any. I’m thankful for any advice.

Comment: `$phoneSql = $phoneSql` this line does nothing.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to add the user_id and phone number to an associative array and build the sql queries and run them in a seperate foreach loop?

Comment: It starts with understanding what you do. But the way you ask your question makes it hard to actually find out what specifically foremost you don't understand. How about starting with reading a book about SQL?

Comment: You might want to re-consider your strategy in your update page.  If I have 20 phone numbers and update 1 of them, your code should only make 1 trip to the database.

Comment: thank you for your replies. @Madara Uchiha, you're right, $phoneSql = $phoneSql does nothing, so I've removed that.

Comment: @hakre, if I re-phrase my question like this. I have a fully functioning, although perhaps a little overly complicated, double foreach loop with if statements that give me a perfectly fine SQL query. How can I send that SQL query to the database in the best way?

Comment: @laura.f: Now that actually sounds differently. But I wonder why you don't know how to send a SQL query to the database. Can you shed some more light?

Comment: @hakre: I've only really learnt how to do it in the way that I show above. Send form input to an update.php and then onto a db.php with the function structure above. I've only been using php for about 6 weeks. A friend of mine taught me what he knew and this is as far as I got. 
So, is it possible to send my $phoneSql query in the way that I've done it before or do I need to learn a different way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you should be doing is using an [`INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) construct, saving you a lot of that logic.

e.g.

```
INSERT INTO phone_number (id, user_id, number) VALUES (...)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE user_id=VALUES(user_id), number=VALUES(number)
```

With this, no need to select, test, then insert/update. You just insert, and MySQL will transparently convert it into an update if a duplicate key error occurs.

Comment: thank you for your answer Marc. I'll think about using the INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE. It seems like an easier solution.